# Getting Started w/ Flow and Mortar

Tags: android, mortar

I have been searching all around the web for a simplified guide on using Mortar and Flow in Android but just found some snippets of code explained.

Its really hard to understand how this library works.

Comment: Check Square site: Check Square site: https://corner.squareup.com/2014/01/mortar-and-flow.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try recently updated samples - now it's possible to realize idea behind it with working samples.

[Flow-Sample](https://github.com/square/flow/tree/master/flow-sample)

[Mortar-Sample](https://github.com/square/mortar/tree/master/mortar-sample)

Also code in libraries itself contains documentation, which helps with grokking with it. Also consider reading these blog articles:

[Advocating against fragments](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html)

[An investigation into Flow and Mortar](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/an-investigation-into-flow-and-mortar/)

and presentations from these guys:

[Presentation by Pierre-Yves Ricau from Square](http://mceconf.com/agenda.html#feb-6)
and [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/pyricau/mce-mortar-andflow)

[Presentation](https://youtu.be/RPRl8fgBiNA?list=PL9Pfzam3fFdeURdCGf1vlBrnMn3MxjvRS) and [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/ambergleam/mortar-and-flow) by Thorben Primke at Droidcon Berlin 2015

[Slides of presentation by Matt Compton](https://speakerdeck.com/ambergleam/mortar-and-flow)

along with blog article provided above. Though the libraries are evolving rapidly and some information in these libraries outdated they're helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can also check out my example project with Mortar / Flow / Dagger2, which is up to date with latest versions: https://github.com/lukaspili/Mortar-Flow-Dagger2-demo

Comment: it helped me a lot while trying to mix Mortar-Flow + Dagger2 + Kotlin. Thank you